# How to fill the tuple values into duplicated/repeated rows in Pyspark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is the dataframe.

```
+-----------+---+
|       name|age|
+-----------+---+
|      Ashok| 23|
|        Jai| 45|
|        Kin| 12|
+-----------+---+
```

I just have repeated the rows by using the below code,

```
df.withColumn('repeated', F.expr('explode(array_repeat(age, 2))')).show() # 2 times repeated 'age' column
```

And the output as follows,

```
+-----------+---+--------+
|       name|age|repeated|
+-----------+---+--------+
|      Ashok| 23|      23|
|      Ashok| 23|      23|
|        Jai| 45|      45|
|        Jai| 45|      45|
|        Kin| 12|      12|
|        Kin| 12|      12|
+-----------+---+--------+
```

Now just want to replace the `repeated` column values by the below `tuple` values in order.

```
fill = ('ABC', 'now', 'fix', 'hello', 'yes', 'no')
```

**Expected**

```
+-----------+---+--------+
|       name|age|repeated|
+-----------+---+--------+
|      Ashok| 23|     ABC|
|      Ashok| 23|     now|
.... .... ...
.... .... ... 
|        Kin| 12|      no|
+-----------+---+--------+
```

Is it possible to achieve the expected result by modifying the above same single line code? (i.e, without using the `map` or any `iterator` method again.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you know that the len of fill will be equal to len of the repeated dataframe?

Comment: @anky yes, it's some how I can manage and still it's dynamic only .. (e.g, splitting the string at run time!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the corresponding element from the list using the row number as the index:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'repeated', 
    F.expr('explode(array_repeat(age, 2))')
).withColumn(
    'repeated', 
    F.array(*[F.lit(f) for f in fill])[F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1))) - 1]
)

df2.show()
+-----+---+--------+
| name|age|repeated|
+-----+---+--------+
|Ashok| 23|     ABC|
|Ashok| 23|     now|
|  Jai| 45|     fix|
|  Jai| 45|   hello|
|  Kin| 12|     yes|
|  Kin| 12|      no|
+-----+---+--------+
```

Comment: @mck Thanks, How it should be, if once we're running this same operation in the lambda expression (i.e, one by one record using `map()`.. because I just want to do some other operation as well on other column and I have the access to Row only at that time and it should be repeated `n` times and append to the main Dataframe)..

Comment: @JaiK Sorry but I don't understand. I don't see any lambda expression or map in your question.

Comment: Here, we're doing only one operation.. but in my actual case I just want to do some other operation along with this. (e.g splitting the string, checking `age`, `name` startswith etc).. So I'm just following the `row` wise opertaion like pandas `apply` method with `lambda`.  e.g `def fn(x): print(x.name, x.age) df.apply(lambda x: row, axis=1)`.. It is more comfortable than doing `multiple column` wise operation like `df.withClm('split', ..).withClm('age' > 21, ..).withClm('name'.startswith(), ..)`.

Comment: In Spark, `apply` isn't available, so you can't use lambda expressions with Spark. This is not pandas I'm afraid, and you have to rely on Spark methods.

Comment: Haaha .. Actually I meant Pyspark's `def fn(x): return x; df.rdd.map(fn)`.. I will give a try. Thanks. :)

Comment: Using `rdd.map` is slower than dataframe methods, and IMO more tedious to use... I'd suggest sticking with the dataframe API.